# React Recoil persist state between routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, recoiljs

I want to use Recoil to share a state between to React Router Routes.
My setup looks something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RecoilRoot>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="/checkin" element={<Checkin />} />
          <Route path="/checkin/confirm" element={<ConfirmCheckin />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </RecoilRoot>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My atom setup looks like this:

```
const checkinItemsState = atom<InventoryItem[]>({
  key: "checkinItemsState",
  default: [],
});
```

In both components i use `useRecoilState(checkinItemsState)`

Now when i open *localhost:3000/checkin* it shows my state and i can modify it. When i then navigate to *localhost:3000/checkin/confirm* my state is just an empty array.

What am I missing here? is there something i misunderstand?

So fare I've tried to wrap my Routes with a component like:

```
const Index: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  useRecoilState(checkinItemsState);

  return (
    <>
      <span>Hello World</span>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

I guessed maybe it was because the state was nowhere referenced when moving between urls. This does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***How*** are you navigating between paths you render routes for? Are you persisting your app state to something more longterm, like localStorage, so it persists through page reloads? From what I can guess you likely ***are not*** persisting the app state and you ***are*** manually updating the URL in the address bar which reloads the page, i.e. remounts the entire app. This is *just* a hunch though.

Comment: I think this could be the issue. To test it i just manually entered the url in the url bar. In hindsight, this probably wasn't the cleverest way.
To still answer your comment: I'm not persisting my states in local storage and im (currently) not using the Link component to navigate.
I'll have to test, if the state persists, when i navigate via a button. I think your comment was maybe the hint i needed.

Comment: Right, if you aren't persisting the state then it's wiped when the page reloads when you manually enter URLs.

Comment: Is persisting state in localStorage a common/reasonable strategy for handling page refreshes? If so, is there a way to have a global trigger for something like `onRefresh()` or `onWindowClose()`?